# Getting generic network error with Zoom Web SDK when meeting is not started. How can I show real error in the modal?

Tags: zoom-sdk

I am getting generic error in Zoom Web SDK 1.9.5 when trying to connect to a meeting that has not started.

```
ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('https://dmogdx0jrul3u.cloudfront.net/1.9.5/lib', '/av');
    ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
    ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();

    ZoomMtg.init({
        leaveUrl: 'URL_HERE',
        isSupportAV: true,
        success: (success) => {
            ZoomMtg.join({
                signature: '{{ $signature }}',
                meetingNumber: '{{ $meeting_number }}',
                userName: '{{ $name }}',
                apiKey: '{{ config('zoom.api_key') }}',
                passWord: '{{ $password }}',
                userEmail: '{{ $email }}',
                success: (success) => {
                    console.log(success)
                },
                error: (error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add internationalization and add a default language to fix this.

Change your code to this,

```
ZoomMtg.setZoomJSLib('https://dmogdx0jrul3u.cloudfront.net/1.9.5/lib', '/av');
    ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
    ZoomMtg.prepareJssdk();
    
    ZoomMtg.i18n.load('en-US');  // Added a default language

    ZoomMtg.init({
        leaveUrl: 'URL_HERE',
        isSupportAV: true,
        success: (success) => {
            ZoomMtg.join({
                signature: '{{ $signature }}',
                meetingNumber: '{{ $meeting_number }}',
                userName: '{{ $name }}',
                apiKey: '{{ config('zoom.api_key') }}',
                passWord: '{{ $password }}',
                userEmail: '{{ $email }}',
                success: (success) => {
                    console.log(success)
                },
                error: (error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            })
        }
    })
```